# Authorize.Net Simple Checkout Attributes?

Tags: e-commerce, authorize.net

Is there a way to add product attributes such as color, size etc. using Authorize.net's Simple Checkout buttons? If so, how?

```
<form action="https://Simplecheckout.authorize.net/payment/CatalogPayment.aspx" method="post" name="PrePage" class="center">
    <input name="LinkId" value="123456" type="hidden">
    <input src="/wp-content/uploads/btn_buynow.png" type="image">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted options for color and size, you would need to either create separate simple checkout options for each combination.  Otherwise, you'll need to use the full API or a shopping cart like solution supporting Authorize.Net.